# Where can I find the default flex 4.5 skins?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, skinning

Can anyone help me locate the default skin files for Flex 4.5. I want to see how the inner shadow effect has been drawn so I can use the same technique in my own custom skins but I can't find them in the SDK.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to search them here `{flex4.5 sdk root}/frameworks/projects/spark/src/spark/skins`. Mobile skins are located here `{flex4.5 sdk root}/frameworks/projects/mobiletheme`.

Comment: To add to this, if you want to create shadow, they probably did it using [filters](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7c48.html)

Comment: @J_A_X: Yes, the sample can be found here `{flex4.5 sdk root}/frameworks/projects/spark/src/spark/skins/spark/PanelSkin.mxml`: `<s:RectangularDropShadow id="dropShadow" blurX="20" blurY="20" alpha="0.32" distance="11" angle="90" color="#000000" left="0" top="0" right="0" bottom="0"/>`

Comment: Perfect thanks! It looks like they layer up lots of rectangles to create the effects rather than using strokes etc